# What is this side-scrolling fighting game for the Amiga?

Tags: amiga, identify-this-game

[image: an Amiga game]

I remember playing this game on an Amiga. I have no idea what it was called.

Comment: @user Please don't answer in comments. Your comment has been removed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That looks like Golden Axe; it's a Sega arcade game ported to home computers including the Amiga by Probe. Details: http://www.lemonamiga.com/?game_id=463

Answer (score 10):

Impressive that you were able to find the image without knowing the name of the game. If you paste the image URL of your post above into [Google's image search](https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en), Google's guess will be "Golden Axe II".

Comment: Another useful engine is TinEye https://www.tineye.com/search  which can complement google's image search quite nicely (though not useful in this example)

Comment: I took a screenshot of some video on YouTube.

Comment: Interestingly, the Google search shows YouTube snapshots. It is the same level stopped at a similar frame, but the chosen playable character is not the one with blue boots and a sword as in the picture above, but rather the Lord of the Rings style dwarf with an axe. I only have recognized the game by the playable character; the image search has rather identified the level design or background art. Google's image search is apparently also searching through videos (which might be the reason for tineye.com not being successful here).